# Can't boot; screen shows white stripes and cloudy patches

Tags: boot, display

My laptop does not boot properly. When I press the on button, the screen does some weird cloud thing with horizontal white stripes. If you can, look at the [video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q61kphyb19m4t2f/VID_20140805_093225.mp4) I made of the laptop turning on. And then the computer stays frozen in that state, no operating system, no booting, nothing. The computer was fine; I shutdown windows last night, and this morning this is what happens,

I also removed the hard drive and tried it again to confirm that it wasn't some weird corruption issue with my OS; the problem persisted.

Any help would be welcome

[image: Example of the screen]

Comment: That is not good. It looks like it's a hardware problem. I'm thinking of overheating or something.

Comment: It looks like an LCD pannel that has a crack, and liquid seeped out or air seeped in? Only based on that is what they can look like around cracks in the pannels, not that I have ever seen this full screened before. OR a LCD pannel that has been heated by very hot sun, or left on the cars dash or next to a space heater and (only) needs to cool back down again. If you view through with a flashlight when off do you see anything that might look like breakage on the other side? did it get dropped? Is the pannel very hot? It is slightly possible to be a power to the pannel (not light) problem also.

Comment: When I connect the PC to an external display with a VGA cable, the display doesn't even recognize that something is connected. I think this means the problem is not on the LCD but on the computer itself... As for overheating, the computer was fine one night and in the morning that happened, so there is 0 chance that this was an overheating problem. I also dropped the computer some 10 inches about one year ago, but this is the first time the computer had any problem like this.

Comment: What about anything else? Does the fan spin, can you hear the hard drive do anything, do any of the lights do anything? Does the power pack LED light up? Which brings up if it is the power that screwed up , it should probably be checked out not tested anymore.

Comment: The fan spins; as for the hard-drive, I will have to test later. What is the power pack LED? The light on the power button turns on, but I don't think that's what you're asking, is it?

Comment: Yes.  The idea of the hard drive would be to Hear the spin up and working operation, to make wild assumptions that the OS is still even loading behind there.  Any clues to the rest of the operations of the system. To feel out if it is only a display issue.  The PSU could be tested for voltage , the unit checked with the battery removed or on battery only. Anyting that gets more info.